# Regra de validação SObject lista de opcao

Tags: validation

Preciso criar uma regra de validação que pega informações de dois objetos.

Tem os campos "Plano" e "Status" no objeto "Oportunidade", o campo "Perfil da empresa" no objeto "Conta" e o campo "Status" no objeto(Personalizado) "Analise de Documentacao".

Minha regra:

```
AND(ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Fechado e ganho"),
$ObjectType.Analise_de_Documentacao__c.Fields.Status__c = "Aprovada",
OR(NOT(ISPICKVAL(Produto__c, "Exacta")),
NOT(ISPICKVAL(Account.Perfil_da_Empresa_Lista_Global__c, "Comprador"))))
```

O problema é que o campo "Status" do objeto "Analise de Documentacao" está dando problema, quando eu deixo o status diferente de "aprovado" a regra valida todas as fases do campo status e não deixa salvar.

Exemplo...: [image]

[image]

[image]

E se eu deixar o status igual a "aprovado" a regra não valida nenhuma fase do campo status e deixa salvar.

Comment: Caique, voce precisa escrever no ingles aqui. Meu portugues nao es bom. :)

Comment: Google Translate @Caique CavalcantiAline caitano ?  
você pode salvar outros o problema de fazê-lo, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer in english, since my portuguese is not really good.

Your formula seems to have some problems.

The field
`$ObjectType.Analise_de_Documentacao__c.Fields.Status__c` is unconnected to the Opportunity being evaluated

You want to replace those with `Analise_de_Documentacao__r.Status` in order to use the status of the current opportunity. (I expect that the lookup from `Opportunity` to `Analise_de_Documentacao__c` to be called `Analise_de_Documentacao__c`. If not, replace the field name with the correct one).

PS: I hope I have understood your problem correctly.